# PayU intigration in Android studio in java

Tags: java, android, payumoney, payu

I am trying to create an activity in the pay button and then trying to integrate the PayU gateway on this button...my request goes in response but does not payU page...

Comment: what is your code? what is the error in the logcat? paste it with your question so anyone can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might help
`public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
/**
 * Adding WebView as setContentView
 */
WebView webView;

/**
 * Context for Activity
 */
Context activity;
/**
 * Order Id
 * To Request for Updating Payment Status if Payment Successfully Done
 */
int mId; //Getting from Previous Activity
/**
 * Required Fields
 */
// Test Variables
/*
private String mMerchantKey = "FCyqqZ";
private String mSalt = "sfBpGA8E";
private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
*/

// Final Variables
private String mMerchantKey = "Your Merchant Key";
private String mSalt = "Salt";
private String mBaseURL = "https://secure.payu.in";


private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
private String mProductInfo = "Food Items"; //Passing String only
private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
private String mServiceProvider = "payu_paisa";
private String mSuccessUrl = "your success URL";
private String mFailedUrl = "Your Failure URL";


boolean isFromOrder;
/**
 * Handler
 */
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

/**
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
    * Setting WebView to Screen
    */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview_for_payumoney);

    /**
     * Creating WebView
     */
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);

    /**
     * Context Variable
     */
    activity = getApplicationContext();

    /**
     * Actionbar Settings
     */
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_online_payment));

    /**
     * Getting Intent Variables...
     */
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        mFirstName = bundle.getString("name");
        mEmailId = bundle.getString("email");
        mAmount = bundle.getDouble("amount");
        mPhone = bundle.getString("phone");
        mId = bundle.getInt("id");
        isFromOrder = bundle.getBoolean("isFromOrder");

        Log.i(TAG, "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);

        /**
         * Creating Transaction Id
         */
        Random rand = new Random();
        String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

        mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

        /**
         * Creating Hash Key
         */
        mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                mTXNId + "|" +
                mAmount + "|" +
                mProductInfo + "|" +
                mFirstName + "|" +
                mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                mSalt);

        /**
         * Final Action URL...
         */
        mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");

        /**
         * WebView Client
         */
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                                           SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                handler.proceed();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("status", true);
                    intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                    intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                    intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("status", false);
                    intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                    intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                    intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this), "PayUMoney");

        /**
         * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
         */
        Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

        mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
        mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
        mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
        mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
        mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
        mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
        mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
        mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
        mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
        mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
        mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

        webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
 *
 * @param webView
 * @param url
 * @param postData
 */
public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url,
                              Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
    sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
        sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
    sb.append("</form></body></html>");

    Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
    webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}

/**
 * Hash Key Calculation
 *
 * @param type
 * @param str
 * @return
 */
public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
    byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
        algorithm.reset();
        algorithm.update(hashSequence);
        byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                hexString.append("0");
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onPressingBack();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    onPressingBack();
}

/**
 * On Pressing Back
 * Giving Alert...
 */
private void onPressingBack() {

    final Intent intent;

    if(isFromOrder)
        intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, ProductInCartList.class);
    else
        intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayUMoneyActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /**
     * Instantiate the interface and set the context
     */
    PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                mHandler = null;
                Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: You may want to read [answer]. A code dump just encourages people to copy & paste from the net, without understanding or evaluating the code. This leads to poor code in production.

Comment: Yes might be this is copy paste but here we all are for the solution for the perticular problem not here to follow the codding standards and structure. This is the solution which I have implemented before and I use this perticular solution for my project obviously I can not give my own code so I got this sample which I follow and I know it is working.